# Stream write stream to read stream

Tags: node.js, streaming

I am using a library in nodejs that can read from a read stream.  I am currently opening a file read stream and passing that to the lib.  However I also need to create the file on the filesystem that I am reading from.  So step 1 is to create a write file stream and stream my data to the file.

1. data write stream -----> file
2. http response <------ read stream file

The thing I don't like about this process is that I have to clean up the file system when I am done.  Is there a way the I can write directly to a read stream and do it all in one step?

**EDIT:**
Concrete example (using https://github.com/ctalkington/node-archiver):

```
// some route
function(req, res, next) {
    var archive = archiver('zip');
    res.attachment("icons.zip");
    archive.pipe(res);

    // I have to create files on file system
    var stream1 = fs.createWriteStream("file1.txt");
    var stream2 = fs.createWriteStream("file2.txt");
    ...
    // all stuff is one streaming to file system

    // now stream stuff from file system to archive
    archive
      .append(fs.createReadStream("file1.txt"), { name: 'file1.txt' })
      .append(fs.createReadStream("file2.txt"), { name: 'file2.txt' })
      .finalize();

}
```

I have no idea how to avoid streaming to file system first.

EDIT:

Simple question is really this:

Can I write to a readable stream?

Comment: Why can't you just pipe the library to the http response?

Comment: what is `archive` supposed to be archiving if not files?

Comment: So but it takes a read stream. So I can write directly to that read stream. Instead of opening a file read stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like such an easy answer, can't believe I missed this.

Looks like I can just use PassThrough:

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough

> Class: stream.PassThrough# This is a trivial implementation of a
>   Transform stream that simply passes the input bytes across to the
>   output. Its purpose is mainly for examples and testing, but there are
>   occasionally use cases where it can come in handy as a building block
>   for novel sorts of streams.

Comment: @remidej how do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the readable stream to the response, or to a writable stream.

To pipe to the client you can do something like:

```
// the response object is a writable stream too.

// Send the headres first (Dont forget these, and change the content type.)

res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});
var resStream  = readableStm.pipe(res);  // readableStm should be a READABLE stream

// listen to the finish ev.
resStream.on('finish', function () {
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: That is part of my last step, however does not explain how to get rid of the first step which is streaming file to file system first.  I was probably confusing the issue so I added a concrete example that I should have added in the first place ;)